# I Can't open Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L00sG.jpg)

I'm completely new to data visualization and I'm trying to figure out why I can't run Jupyter Notebook.

This is the error that is produced when trying to launch Jupyter:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\matfo\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", 
line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\matfo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 49, in 
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
File "C:\Users\matfo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in 
from zmq import backend
File "C:\Users\matfo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in 
reraise(*exc_info)
File "C:\Users\matfo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
raise value[enter image description here][2]
File "C:\Users\matfo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in 
_ns = select_backend(first)
File "C:\Users\matfo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
File "C:\Users\matfo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in 
from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from partially initialized 
module 'zmq.backend.cython' (most likely due to a circular import) 
(C:\Users\matfo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py)
```

Comment: What happens if you open the ``CMD.exe`` prompt and type ``jupiter notebook``?

Comment: another error   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matfo\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\matfo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 49, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop

Comment: File "C:\Users\matfo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Users\matfo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\matfo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value

Comment: File "C:\Users\matfo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Users\matfo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)

Comment: File "C:\Users\matfo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from partially initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\matfo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py)